# Difference b/w Single and double underscore in PHP Zend Framwork

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am a new be to start work on zend framwork. i got an example quick start from zend site. when i review the code then i found single and double underscore that is specious to me. below is the code...

```
1.
    protected $_comment;
    protected $_created;
    protected $_email;
    protected $_id;

2. 
   public function setComment($text)
    {
        $this->_comment = (string) $text;
        return $this;
    }
3.
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $method = 'set' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid guestbook property');
        }
        $this->$method($value);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look on this:

[PHP Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

> **Caution**
>   PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical.
>   It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP
>   unless you want some documented magic functionality.

[Zend Framework Naming Conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)

> For **methods** on objects that are declared with the "private" or
>   "protected" modifier, the first character of the method name must be
>   an underscore. This is the only acceptable application of an
>   underscore in a method name. Methods declared "public" should never
>   contain an underscore.
>
> For instance **variables** that are declared with the "private" or
>   "protected" modifier, the first character of the variable name must be
>   a single underscore. This is the only acceptable application of an
>   underscore in a variable name. Member variables declared "public"
>   should never start with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

A double underscore represents a [PHP Magic Method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), where as a single underscore (by convention only) denotes a class method or property is private or at least protected.

For example you'd expect

```
protected function _doThis() {}
```

But not

```
public function _doThat() {}
```